# AWS Glue Data Catalog with partitioned table over S3 files and different schemas in partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

Is it possible to create a partitioned table in AWS Glue Data Catalog over AWS S3 files and have a different data schemas in different partitions of this table?

If so, will I be able to create this partitioned table as an external table in Redshift with help of Redshift Spectrum and query it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are of json/parquet type, then define the table such that it includes all the columns - some columns may be present in some partitioned files and others in other partitioned files.

If the files are of csv type, then you need to have the columns present in the same order in each file but each file may not include all the possible columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to create the table in Glue catalog, manually create the schema there and then create the table in Redshift over the meta info from catalog? Or Glue crawler can automatically discover the schema of the table and still attach the brand-new files (which will arrive later ) to this table even in case such files will have a different schema? Or in such case (new files with different schema) the Glue crawler will try to create a brand-new table in the catalog?

Comment: Or in case of manual table creation in Glue catalog - the Glue crawlers will not run, and I will be able to manually store the brand-new files with different schemas in different partitions of that table on AWS S3? Do I need to manually refresh the table in Glue somehow after that - or the new data will be immediately available for querying .. Let's say from Redshift  Spectrum, in case I previously successfully connected such external table to Redshift?

Comment: You can create the table manually in Athena console using CREATE TABLE stmt. When you copy the files to the relevant s3 path, you need to add the partitions using ALTER TABLE ...ADD PARTITION stmt. If you use partition projection, you don't need to add the partitions using ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION stmt.

Comment: Once you have the table created in Glue catalogue, you can create external table in redshift pointing to the table in Glue catalogue and you can query it using Redshift spectrum.